# Showing that $HTH = e^{-i \frac{\pi}{8} \sigma_x}$ (quantum gates)

Tags: matrices, quantum-mechanics

I'm trying to prove that an arbitrary single qubit unitary (read: unitary two by two matrix, and thus rotation up to a phase) can be composed from Hadamard and T gates, given by
$ H = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1 \\
1 & -1\\
\end{array} \right)$, $ T = \left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & e^{i \pi/4}\\
\end{array} \right)$

The proof is not so difficult, but I'm having some trouble with one of the first steps: showing that $HTH = e^{-i \frac{\pi}{8}  \sigma_x}$

I suppose this should follow rather easily, but honestly I don't see it. I know that you can write $T = e^{-i \pi/8 \sigma_z}$ and that $H$ is a pi rotation about the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\hat{x}+\hat{z})$ axis, but I don't know how to write that in exponentials, and I don't know how to get the matrix product (which I can work out of course) into the desired exponential form either.

I assume this should be rather trivial, but I just can't find it sadly.

Comment: Actually, I just had an insight. It is of course true that T^4 = Z, the pauli Z matrix. Moreover, HZH = X, the pauli X matrix. So it would seem to make sense that if X is a pi rotation about the x-axis, that HTH is then a fourth of this rotation about the same axis. Not very formal I suppose, but it seems plausible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For exponentials involving the Pauli matrices its generally a good idea to use the formula: $$e^{i\theta\sigma}=\cos\left(\theta\sigma\right) + i\sin\left(\theta\sigma\right)$$

Then use the Taylor series for $\cos$ and $\sin$: $$e^{i\theta\sigma} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(i\theta\sigma)^{2n}}{(2n)!} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(i\theta\sigma)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$

Then use that the Paulis are Hermitian and unitary so $\sigma^2 = I$: 
\begin{align}
e^{i\theta\sigma} &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(i\theta)^{2n}}{(2n)!} I + \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(i\theta)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\sigma\\
&= \cos(\theta)I + i\sin(\theta)\sigma
\end{align}

Can you see how to apply this technique to your problem?

Comment: Hm, yes, I think I see it. I can use this to write out the expression into matrix form, and using Euler I can show that this is actually equal to the product of the three matrices. Makes sense, thanks a bunch!

Comment: @user3183724 No problem. The relation $e^{i\theta\sigma} = \cos(\theta)I + i\sin(\theta)\sigma$ gets used all the time in quantum information theory and quantum mechanics more generally. Its a major (if not the major) reason the Paulis are so nice to work with.